# VBS: How to get the filesize with special FileDialog?

Tags: vbscript

```
Function FileDialog() 
  Dim oExec1: Set oExec1=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input type=file id=FILE" & ">" & "<" & "script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & "/script>""" )
  Dim sPathfile: sPathfile = oExec1.StdOut.ReadAll
  sPathfile = Replace( sPathfile, vbCRLF, "" )
  FileDialog = sPathfile
End Function
```

change to:
Function FileDialog(filesize)

filesize will return the value of bytes of the selected file

Answer (score 0):

Read [Function Statement (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa(v=vs.84).aspx) document and pass the argument **by reference** as follows:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim nFileSize: nFileSize = -1      ' for test that `byRef` declaration works 

strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & FileDialog( nFileSize)
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & nFileSize

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit

Function FileDialog( byRef xSize) 
  Dim oExec1
  Set oExec1=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input type=file id=FILE" & ">" & "<" & "script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & "/script>""" )
  Dim sPathfile: sPathfile = oExec1.StdOut.ReadAll
  sPathfile = Replace( sPathfile, vbCRLF, "" )
  If Len(sPathfile) > 0 Then
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(sPathfile)
      xSize = .Size                  ' the size, in bytes, of the specified file
    End With 
  Else
    ' No file chosen: red "×" or Esc or Cancel pressed
    xSize = 0
  End If
  FileDialog = sPathfile
End Function
```

Read [**ByRef** and **ByVal** Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101(v=vs.84).aspx) article as well.